# Add a space after a ending dot of a sentence

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

How can I add a space after **the ending dot of a sentence**? So dots like in `"1.2"` should be unaffected. Also if there is already a space, then there should not be a space added.

```
text1 = "This is a sample text. Just 1.2 to test.To add a space after the dot...Okay."
```

Result desired:

```
"This is a sample text. Just 1.2 to test. To add a space after the dot... Okay. "
```

**EDIT:**
As pointed out in the comments: The text could also end and start with a number:

```
text2 = "I watched football.10 people played in 2 teams, my friend was player number 7. 20 minutes later the game ended with the score 2:1.Then I went home."
```

Comment: Just for answerers sake, can you be more precise about the rules? Clearly not each dot is affected. And other exceptions (or not) come to my mind too e.g. `"1.2"`, `"..."`.

Comment: @Kuba This is true. I will add some more details

Comment: BTW, I wonder the necessity of the braces (`List`).

Comment: Can your text contain sentences ending with a number? Starting with a number? Like this: "I watched football.10 people played in 2 teams, my friend was player number 7. 20 minutes later the game ended."

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ Good point. Yes, the text could also end and start with a number. Hmm...then it gets really difficult to solve, I guess.

Comment: @james thanks for the edit but please pay more attention. What about "`Okay."`?

Comment: @Kuba Oh, my mistake. Fixed it. Thanks for spotting it.

Comment: I also wonder what really is it that you want to realize. It is strange to also have a space at the end of a string.

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ Well this is just for consistency I guess. The aim is really just to add a space after every sentence.

Comment: @james OK. To that end, I updated the rule, again. Please check it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For latest requirement:

```
rule = RegularExpression["(?!\\d\\.\\d)(\\w\\.+)(?! )(\\w?)"] -> "$1 $2";
StringReplace[rule] @ {text1, text2}
```

> ```
> {"This is a sample text. Just 1.2 to test. To add a space after the dot... Okay. ", 
>  "I watched football. 10 people played in 2 teams, my friend was player number 7. 20 minutes later the game ended with the score 2:1. Then I went home. "}
> ```

"Negative Lookahead" (`"(?!...)"`) is used, BTW.

---

**Older-er-er response**

```
StringReplace[text, RegularExpression["(\\w\\.)(\\w)"] -> "$1 $2"]
```

`"\\w"` means word characters, including letters, digits and the underscore `_`. `"\\."` means a period/dot literally. So the regular expression means to find a string pattern with length three: a word character followed by a period and followed by a word character.

Parentheses mean a group, and `"$n"` where `n` is an integer represents the contents in the `n`-th group.

So the whole operation is to add a blank between the two groups after locating them by the string pattern.

Comment: Awesome ! Thanks a lot ! Could you just add one or two comments about the terms withing the RegularExpression function ? I don't quite understand how you did it. Thanks !

Comment: @james OK, let me add some explanations.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation.

Comment: @james But you changed the problem?

Comment: Kuba's comment made me realize that there is actually more to the question that I thought, and that I need to be more specific.

Comment: @james See my update.

Comment: Very nice !! Thanks a lot. What do you mean by "negative lookahead" ?

Comment: @james I think it a technique in regular expression and I conceive it as to take the NOT logical operation.

Comment: @james Lookahead does what it sounds like in Regex. It looks ahead to see if the next set of characters match its pattern (negative lookahead sees if it doesn't) *without* actually capturing any characters. In the example, it lets you check if the character after a `.` is a space, or that you aren't trying to split `1.2`.

Answer (score 8):

```
StringReplace[text, "." ~~a:Except[DigitCharacter|WhitespaceCharacter|"."] :> ". "<> a]
```

> {"This is a sample text. Just 1.2 to test. To add a space after the 
>   dot... Okay."}

Also

```
StringReplace[text, a:LetterCharacter|"."~~"." ~~b:LetterCharacter:> a<>". "<>b ]
```

> same result

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you also try the new sample text that I added to the question ?

Comment: @james, just did.

Answer (score 5):

```
StringReplace[StringReplace[text, "." -> ". "], ". " ~~ EndOfString -> "."]
```

> {"This is a sample text. Just to test. To add a space after the dot. Okay."}

Answer (score 5):

```
text= {"This is a sample text.Just to test.To add a space after the dot.Okay."}

StringReplace[text, 
 WordBoundary ~~ "." ~~ Except[WhitespaceCharacter, WordBoundary] :> ". "]
```

> ```
> {"This is a sample text. Just to test. To add a space after the dot. Okay."}
> ```

Or

```
StringReplace[text, a : WordCharacter ~~ "." ~~ b : WordCharacter :> a <> ". " <> b]
```

> ```
> {"This is a sample text. Just to test. To add a space after the dot. Okay."}
> ```

Both solutions correctly handle the cases when there already is a whitespace character after the dot:

```
text2 = {"This is a sample text. Just to test.To add a space after the dot. Okay."};

StringReplace[text2, a : WordCharacter ~~ "." ~~ b : WordCharacter :> a <> ". " <> b]
```

> ```
> {"This is a sample text. Just to test. To add a space after the dot. Okay."}
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you also try the new sample text that I added to the question ?